# Why does my TextEditingController not work?

Tags: flutter

What I am trying to do is i am trying to create a texteditingcontroller field as much as user wants. But the issue is that when I print or try to use the value `item.text`, it says null. How can I solve it?

```
class TextEditingModel {
   TextEditingController hint =  TextEditingController(text: '');

  TextEditingModel ({this.hint});

   TextEditingModel hintchange(){
     print(hint);
     return hint;
   }
}
```

```
List<TextEditingModel> texteditingcontrollers = [];

   RaisedButton(
    child: Text('Add Controller',
    onPressed: (){
     setState(() {

   TextEditingModel model = TextEditingModel();
  texteditingcontrollers.add(model);

   });
   },),

  for(final item in texteditingcontrollers)
  TextFormField(controller: item.hintchange()),
```

Comment: Can you separate mode class and its uses

Comment: Did it.Check the update please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `TextEditingModel` at `hintchange()` its return type `TextEditingModel` and it should be same as `hint` data type. Also while like to have default value and optional parameter on hint, like

```dart
class TextEditingModel {
  TextEditingController? hint;

  TextEditingModel({this.hint});

  TextEditingController hintchange() {
    return hint ?? TextEditingController(text: '');
  }
}
```

And use case is working the way you did.

```dart
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  List<TextEditingModel> texteditingcontrollers = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          for (final item in texteditingcontrollers)
            TextFormField(controller: item.hintchange()),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            TextEditingModel model =
                TextEditingModel(hint: TextEditingController(text: "Asda"));
            texteditingcontrollers.add(model);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```